# What's happened to pandas data reader using stooq?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas-datareader

I have built a set of scripts that obtain and perform technical analysis on stocks using pandas-datareader. It has been up and working now for 6-8 months without problems.

Suddenly this week the datareader function is returning empty frames eg:-

```
    import pandas_datareader as web
    BAC = web.DataReader("AAPL.US", "stooq")
    print BAC
```

Has the format changed- do i need to phrase it differently now?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bug was introduced in 0.7.0 which automatically appends `.US` to every ticker. This is likely being reverted in 0.8.0 (see this pull request), but for now, use:

`BAC = web.DataReader("AAPL", "stooq")`

as a workaround.